# using runas with a password and a sql command

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I have a batch file with the following script (which i found here at stackoverflow)

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
start runas "/user:domain\username" "cmd.exe"
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
goto :EOF
@end
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("mypass{ENTER}");
```

where mypass is the username's password.

this works perfectly and a new commandline window opens as the new user!
the problem is that i now need to run an sqlcmd with parameter and I can't find any way to write a batch that does both things together (open the new window as another user together with the command with parameters)

the sql command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" -S "my.server.com, 1234" -d "myDataBase" -E -b -q "EXEC myDataBase.[dbo].[myTable] @parameter=1"
```

I tried moving the whole sql command to another batch (myBatch.bat) file and change the first batch to this:

```
start runas "/user:domain\username" "myBatch.bat"
```

but it doesn't work.

any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`runas /user:domain\user "cmd.exe /k c:\path\to\mybatch.bat test"`

cmd /k to keep the console open after the batch execution, or cmd /c to close it

Comment: and what should I do if one of the parameters for mybatch.bat needs parenthesis (" ")? for example the typical run of myBatch.bat would be: c:\path\to\mybatch.bat "this is my test parameter"

Comment: `runas /user:domain\user "cmd.exe /k c:\path\to\mybatch.bat """ this is my test""" "`